# jquery change doesn't work on select

Tags: jquery, html, select

Why doesn't this work? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm certain that jquery is working on the page.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/derweco.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#numbers').change(function(){
            alert('other value');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home">
    <select id="numbers">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you [*adapt your code to the example in the documentation*](http://api.jquery.com/change/), it works.

Answer (score 7):

You need to wrap your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or shorter form `$(function() {...});` to make sure all of your DOM elements have been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code.

```
$(function() {
    $('#numbers').change(function(){
        alert('other value');
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FWdzH/)**

Answer (score 3):

when you want to register an event like onchange you should put it inside the

```
    $(documet).ready(function(){
$('#numbers').change(function(){
        alert('other value');
    });
});
```

notice that $(documet).ready() is equal  to $() as Felix pointed out !

Also notice that you can apply event registration using plain Javascript  as follow:

```
window.onload=function(){};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/derweco.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ //Added DOM ready 
        $('#numbers').change(function(){
            alert('other value');
        });
     });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="home">
    <select id="numbers">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This work for me

```
$(function() {
   $('#numbers').change(function(){
       console.log('other value');
   });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.